# For loop crashes on input for unknown reasons

Tags: c, for-loop, crash

Alrighty folks, so I'm sitting here staring at my screen as my program crashes repeatedly. I've tried several different fixes for the first for loop. The problem is, I don't want to change any variables in the first for loop, I simply want that as my first test loop. The problem is, it won't run without appending a variable in the loop (like x++ or something that changes a variable). I always get to user input just fine, enter a number and then bam. Crash.

```
while (((x%2!=0)&&(y%2==0)) || ((x%2==0)&&(y%2!=0))) {
    int numtest;

    numtest=x%y;

    while (numtest==1 && x<=i) {
        a=(x*x)-(y*y);
        b=2*x*y;
        c=(x*x)+(y*y);

        x++;
        y++;
        printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
    }
}
```

I'm just not clear on why it crashes even though I have everything that I need. Anyone see the fix?

EDIT: Edited with suggestions from below
EDIT 2: Found crash was due to infinite while loop. Changing to if statement stops crashing.

Comment: Use `while` instead of `for`

Comment: what error does it show when it crashes ?

Comment: Tried and still crashes.

Comment: Simply says "Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))"  It'll sit for a few seconds and then hit me with that response.

Comment: just show us the whole code

Comment: well `numtest=x%y;` == 0 so the inner loop is never accessed which causes an infinite loop

Comment: Incidentally, `((x%2!=0)&&(y%2==0)) || ((x%2==0)&&(y%2!=0))` can be simplified to `(x & 1) ^ (y & 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this `for (x=2, y=1;((x%2!=0)&&(y%2==0)) || ((x%2==0)&&(y%2!=0));i) {` with this

```
for (x=2, y=1;((x%2!=0)&&(y%2==0)) || ((x%2==0)&&(y%2!=0));) {
```

or better yet as *mlwn* suggested , use a `while` loop

```
x = 2;
y = 1;
while (((x%2!=0)&&(y%2==0)) || ((x%2==0)&&(y%2!=0))) {
```

Comment: I tried that for loop suggestion a while ago and for some reason doing a while loop doesn't change anything. Program still crashes.

Comment: Actually found out if I make the first loop an if statement and then follow that with a while, I get my desired output. Not crashing either. Thanks to mlwn and Farouk for their help.